# Solving for the Real part of a complex number

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following two complex values:

$A = a e^{j \omega t + \theta }$

$B = b e^{j \omega t + \theta}$

where $j = \sqrt{-1}$.

I am trying to find the real part of the product AB.

So far I've done this: $A B = a b e^{2 j \omega t+ \theta}$

I am not sure where to go from here with the complex variables...

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question

Comment: The exponent should be $2j\omega t + 2\theta$

Answer (score 1):

$$A B = a b e^{2 (j \omega t + \theta)} = \underbrace{a b [ \cos (2 (j \omega t + \theta))}_{real} + i \sin (2 (j \omega t + \theta))]$$

Comment: I forgot to mention that for engineering notation, j = sqrt(-1)

Comment: A recommendation:  Always update your *problem* with such information (rather than make a comment), so that helpers will better see it.  (See my edit to your problem.)

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. In regards to the solution, it is still imaginary because j is in the real part right? Would I then have to take the magnitude of the solution?

Comment: @articat:  No.  A complex number $z$ is made of a real part and an imaginary part.  $z = {\rm real~part} + {\rm imaginary~part} = \underbrace{a}_{real} + \underbrace{i b}_{imaginary}$.  You are thinking of the *magnitude*.